# CakePHP: Database connection 'Mysql' is missing, or could not be created

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Out of nowhere, I'm getting the following error when trying to connect to my legacy CakePHP application:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MissingConnectionException' with message 'Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.' 
in /myapproot/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php:239 
Stack trace: #0 /myapproot/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php(101):
DboSource->__construct(Array) #1 /myapproot/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3260):
ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default') #2 
/myapproot/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1223): Model->getDataSource() #3 
/myapproot/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1396): Model->schema() #4 
/myapproot/app/Lib/Log/Engine/DatabaseLogger.php(14): Model->create() #5 
/myapproot/lib/Cake/Log/CakeLog.php(204): DatabaseLogger->write('error', 
'[MissingConnect...') #6 /myapproot/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(118): 
CakeLog::write(3, '[MissingConnect...') #7 [internal function]: 
ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(M 
in /myapproot/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php on line 239
```

This application was working fine as recently as last Friday, and to my knowledge, there have been no configuration changes to the server. The error log for my site shows that this started early this morning.

Here is the relevant part of my database.php file. Again, none of this has changed in the last few days:

```
public $default = array(
            'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'login' => 'user',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'database' => 'nc_live2',
            'prefix' => '',
            //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
}
```

I have tried specifying the `unix_socket` in database.php, to no avail. I've also tried changing 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1.' No joy. Nothing changes when I specify the port, either.

I'm utterly baffled as to why this problem is suddenly manifesting itself.

I'm running CakePHP 2.8 on CentOS 7, fully patched. MariaDB version 10.0.36

UPDATE: Here is some netstat output that shows mysqld is only listening for IPV6 connections:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      2108/mysqld
```

Still no joy even after manually setting the bind to 0.0.0.0. That got 3306 listening on IPV4, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you telnet to your mysql server? telnet localhost 3306

Comment: We do not allow telnet on this box, but I'm able to log in to mysql from the command line. I've updated the post with some netstat output. For some reason, 3306 is only listening for IPV6 connections.